# How can I pass a list of multiple anonymous functions to plot2d?

Tags: maxima

I am using maxima.
I'd like to get plot2d of more than one anonymous function, but I do not know how to do it.

I would like to know how to dynamically generate functions like taylor ().
For that, I think that it is possible to create lambda expressions by editing character strings programmatically.
I'd like to generate multiple functions regularly using strings, convert them to symbols, and adapt to plot2d ().
Then all the dynamically generated functions on gnuplot will be displayed on the same screen.

This is what I want to do.

[Mr. Robert Dodier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871096/robert-dodier) said that I do not need string manipulation in many cases and I want you to omit what I do not need for my purpose.

My purpose is simple, I just want to dynamically create a function list to pass to plot2d ().
Certainly, when passing multiple functions normally to plot2d (), I do not need to dynamically generate it in the program, but I can enumerate it by hand as it is in the answer.
But, if I can make my own function sequence that changes regularly like taylor () and pass it to the argument of plot2d (), I can understand how each function changes.
It is my purpose to compare functions with each other, but rather than comparing them individually by handwriting, the purpose is to compare them by passing them to plot2d () dynamically generated by the program.

if you'd kindly teach me.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. From where are you getting your input? I am trying to figure out if strings are necessary -- in many cases, parsing strings is not necessary. In order to help figure it out, please say more about the overall purpose of your project. Please include things that seem unnecessary or irrelevant to you -- it will all help others understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `plot2d(l, ...)` where `l` is a list of lambda expressions.

For example

```
plot2d ([lambda ([x], x^2), lambda ([x], sin(x)), lambda ([x], cos(x))], [x, 0, 1]);
```

seems to have the effect you want.

Comment: If I write a lambda expression, I know what I can do. How can I generate a list of lambda expressions from a string?
In this case, can I convert strings to symbols using eval_string ()?

Comment: I can help you with this also. Please edit your question to include the new part. It will help a lot of you describe the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish. Be sure to include an example of the input you expect.

Comment: Once, as you pointed out, I added an explanation of what I would like to do.

Is this OK?